Correct projection for WA, OR, ID
We are trying to make estimates of infrastructure within 1000 ft within Washington, Oregon, and Idaho. Is UTM-11 ok, or should we use something else like Albers Equal Area?

or UTM-10 https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/26910/

Neither UTM nor an equal area projection are ideal for distance calculations. If you're using a buffer, see if there's a geodesic/geodetic option. Similar for other tools you're using.

Why aren't you using each state's state plane CRS?

It's all in one map. It seems to be fine for UTM-11. Using different CRS, the calculations are the same
